# use InvalideRect() to change a GDI shape

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I asked my question yesterday but could not get a correct answer. now ill ask it more clearly.
using win api I created a window and a button. infront of the button there is a circle drawn in green color. once the button is pressed the circle should turn to red color.

(I'm using C++, and mingw compiler.)

here is my code

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 HDC hDC;
 HBRUSH brusha;
 brusha=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));

 switch(msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {

        b=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            "BUTTON",
            "red",
            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
            BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            350,
            100,
            100,
            40,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
    }
    break;


    case WM_PAINT:
    {


    hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    SelectObject(hDC,brusha);
    Ellipse(hDC, 20, 20, 100, 100);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
      switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case BUTTON:
            {
            brusha=CreatSolideBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
            InvalidateRect( hWnd,0,false);

            }
        }
  break;


      case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);

  }
```

this compiles without errors. but nothing happens on button click

Comment: @RaymondChen this compiles withour errors, but nothing happens on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that you you always draw with a green brush. Look at your code

```
HBRUSH brusha;
brusha=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));

switch(msg)
{
    ...
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
    hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    SelectObject(hDC,brusha);
    ...
```

In this code `brusha` is always going to be a green brush when you go into `WM_PAINT`.

You seem to think that just because you assign a red brush to the `brusha` variable in the `WM_COMMAND` part that somehow that is going to be remembered for the next paint, but that's not true. Remember that in C++ variables are created afresh each time you enter a function, and destroyed each time you exit a function. So the way you have written the code cannot work.

Probably the simplest way is to make the `hbrusha` variable `static`. Static variables are *not* created and destroyed each time you enter and exit a funciton. Something like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBRUSH brusha;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        brusha=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0)); // set the brush green on create

        ...

        break;


    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case BUTTON:
            brusha=CreatSolideBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
            InvalidateRect( hWnd,0,false);
        }
        break;

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: great answer. thanks a lot. I was finding for help in this issue from 2 days ago. without your help I would have never found this. thanks again. this worked correctly... :)

Comment: Note that this code leaks GDI objects since you never destroy the brushes you created.